# AngularJS selectively showing dynamic directives

Tags: angularjs

I created a few directives. When the page load all directives is loaded. All directives appear. I want to show  directives when the function is called. For example when `$scope.getConsultant` is called the `consultant` directive must be appear. Other directives should not appear. I have too many html template but I didn't write here. How can I control? What is the best way?

**Directives**

```
<div class='container'>
   <div consultant></div>
   <div investment></div>
   <div portfolio></div>
</div>
```

```
window.ngApp.directive('investment', function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'lib/view/investment.html'
    };
});

window.ngApp.directive('consultant', function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'lib/view/consultant.html'
    };
});
window.ngApp.directive('portfolio', function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'lib/view/portfolio.html'
    };
});
```

**AngularJS**

```
var ngApp = angular.module('tapusor', []);
window.ngApp.controller('controllerHome', ['$scope', '$controller',
    function ($scope, $controller) {
        $scope.lat =25.33544;
        $scope.lng =13.21687;
        $scope.getConsultant = function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: "/",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    lat: $scope.lat,
                    lng: $scope.lng
                },
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $scope.resConsultant = data;
                }
            });
        }

        $scope.searchInvestment = function () {            
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: "/",
                dataType: 'json',
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                data: {
                    lat:$scope.lat,
                    lng:$scope.lng
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $scope.resInvestment = data;
                }    
            })
        } 

        $scope.portfolio = function () {            
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: "/",
                dataType: 'json',
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                data: {
                    lat:$scope.lat,
                    lng:$scope.lng
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $scope.resPortfolio = data;
                }    
            })
        }              
    }
]);
```

Comment: Instead of `$.ajax` use [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, Satpal is right, use Angular builtins wherever possible.

You need some variable that you can key off of to determine which directive is currently being 'shown'. Then, on each one, you can use that with ng-if.

```
<div class='container'>
   <div consultant ng-if="$shown == 'consultant'"></div>
   <div investment ng-if="$shown == 'investment'"></div>
   <div portfolio ng-if="$shown == 'portfolio'"></div>
</div>
```

This is just a rough example, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: I'd personally say that a ngSwitch would work better in this context, keeping the matching logic a little more simplistic, using a Angular directive as designed, and not basically reinventing the wheel.

Comment: As @scales pointed out, you could check out ngSwitch, but performance-wise it depends on your use-case. Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44583939/angular-ng-if-vs-ng-switch-performance).

Comment: Either/or would work. With so few options the ng-if may be better performance wise, though it's probably milliseconds. Each approach is viable though, and the ng-switch might be more clear.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommending restructuring this code to take advantage of an ngSwitch.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch

If the goal is to have other directives not appear, then loading the data, and then using an ngSwitch will do just that.